# Add Using statement to every aspx-code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may be a pretty basic question (or not, I don't know), but I couldn't find any answer to this.

I'm in the process of refactoring an older Webapplication. I'm moving the App_Code folder (which is pretty huge) to a seperate Class Library, for one thing.

I'm wondering if there is a way to reference the classes in the DLL in every .aspx file in the entire web-app, without having to open every .aspx-file and adding the 'Using' statement manually. Can I add something in my web.config for example to reference the DLL automatically?
I'm not in the mood to open up every .aspx page one by one to add this - because there are a lot of them.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: C# and vb.net? Which one?

Comment: Judging from his title's inclusion of `Using`, I'd guess C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to the Web.config file in your views directory(ies):

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Your.Namespace.Here" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

There should already be some default namespaces included.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add your own namespaces in the web config under pages\namespaces:

```
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <namespaces>
    <pages>
```